# What does a ? do in a new Type?[5] assignment?

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code, and I have no idea what the `?` means in the construct.

What is it doing?

```
myObj_Request r = new myObj_Request(); //instantiate intial object
r.Channels = new ChannelSequence();    //initial object has another object in channels
r.Channels.ChannelType = new ChannelType?[5] { .. } // ok so we have 5 channeltypes...
                                                    // but  that ? infront of [5] ?
```

Comment: This has many many duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nullable type. Difference?

```
int c = 5; // you can set only numbers

int? d = null; // you can set int or null
int? e = 5;
```

`int?` is <strike>basically</strike> **exactly** equal to `Nullable<int>`.

Here's the reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**[edit]**

So `new ChannelType?[5]` is an array (5 elements) of `Nullable<ChannelType>`.

Comment: It's not basically equal to; it's exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, exactly:) I wrote it badly, but nvm:)

Answer (score 1):

Nullable type: check [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) . You'll find more here.

Answer (score 0):

"?" this will be used to make VeluTypes to NullableTypes

Ex:

Int is value type. You can't assign null to it. If you declare it like int?...you can assign null here